# C++ templated function that maybe wants a reference

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I have a function that, to simplify a bit, looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
T DoStuff(const vector<T>& data) {
    T ret_data;
    for (const T datum : data) { /* ... */ }
    return ret_data;
}
```

Usually T is an int or a string.  If this weren't templated code, I'd use a `const string&` but a `const int` in that for loop.  And, of course, I can just use int references (`const T& datum`).  But I'm curious if there's a proper idiom for this.

I am well aware that in my particular case it won't matter.  This is purely pedagogical today.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: I would worry more about passing the `const vector<T> data` by value to this function because that effectively makes a copy of the argument passed to the function call. To no avail because it's marked `const` so you dno't want/can't to modify it anyway.

Comment: Are you saying you want one version which, in the for loop, will use references, and which in the other will make copies? I think your only choice is to make two versions (e.g. `DoStuffRef` or `DoStuffCopy`). Personally I would just do `for (auto& datum : data) { ... }` and be done with it.

Comment: The question is about idiom.  That said, I corrected the missing reference in the arg (@Claudiu).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no convention or idiom for this, no. Generally I'd just accept references ∀ `T`, but you can specialise for the built-in types if you really want.

Comment: Barring dissent, and in light of the other (mostly non-) answers, I suspect this may be the right answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Even if using const reference would be the trivial/acceptable way to do it,
you may use [call_traits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/call_traits.htm) from boost

and do:

```
template<typename T>
T DoStuff(const vector<T>& data) {
    T ret_data;
    for (typename boost::call_traits<T>::param_type datum : data) { /* ... */ }
    return ret_data;
}
```