# Practial solution to overload ambiguity between pass by reference and pass by value in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, pass-by-reference

I have a class template for a 3d vector class that looks kind of like (abbreviated):

```
template<typename T>
class vector3
{
public:

  typedef vector3<T> self;

  self& operator*(T& a);
  self& operator*(T a);
  T x,y,z;

};
```

Both of the operator* overloads 'self multiply' the vector times a scalar, and return *this.

I want to be able to use the class template like this:

```
vector3<double> vv;
double scalar;

vv*scalar;
vv*0.5;
```

The overload ambiguity is clear, and 'just get it to work' kind of solutions are available and have been discussed in other SA questions.

If you remove operator*(T& a), everything will compile, but you (at least in theory), lose some performance benefit from passing by value when you don't really need to (right?)

If you remove operator*(T a), you can't do vv*0.5.

If you rename one of them, you lose a lot of code clarity in cases where all these operations intuitively make sense, math-wise.

Is there any way to retain the pass by reference when it makes sense, but remove the overload ambiguity?  What's the best way to make sure the vector3 template accommodates both expressions above?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to overload operator *= for this? Doing uu = vv*0.5; should modify only uu, according to the convention most people are used to.

Comment: Pretty much the same as http://stackoverflow.com/q/33024041/560648

Comment: First and foremost, operator* should be a free-standing function, not a member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best choice for you is

```
self operator * (const T& a) const;
```

There are three moments:

1. Using `const T&` instead of `T` or `T&`. Modern compilers are smart, they will optimize the code and pass small types by value instead of reference.
2. The operator `*` should not change the operands.
3. The operator `*` should return a value but not a reference.

Comment: I found this reply most appropriate, thanks. 

A follow up question about the convention of returning a new object:  For a longer expression, where many instances of 'self' would be created, isn't this a ton of overhead and potential lost performance?  Does one rely on the compiler to do a good enough job of RVO etc?

Comment: Sure the compiler will optimize it

Answer (score 0):

Just make the other one take an *rvalue* reference:

```
self operator*(T& a);   // for 'scalar'
self operator*(T&& a);  // for 0.5
```

Although, do you really have a different implementation for `operator*` for the two different cases? You probably just want:

```
template <typename U,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::decay_t<U>, T>::value>>
self operator*(U&& a);  // for both
```

---

Note that `operator*` should return a value. `operator*=` should return a reference.

Comment: Using `T&&` is pointless here because the argument should not be modified.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method that takes an rvalue as parameter as Barry described.

Or your template parameter could be `const` if the implementation does not modify it. In this case you could have only one method taking a `const` reference:

```
self operator*(const T& a) const;
```